# One man band short animation - crediting and credits

Tags: post-production

I've been creating a short animation (1 min) to demonstrate and showcase a FUI (Futuristic User Interface). No one else was involved, other than third party advice and support. No unions involved.

A summary of potential sources to credit would include:

- Myself (everything not mentioned below)
- Music (third party, CC BY NC)
- 1 x 3D Model (third party, CC)
- based on Novel xxx.

I was also thinking of adding a "Special thanks to" the following

- Supervisor (support, feedback, etc)
- Employer (support in studies)
- Wife (long suffering in my academic pursuits)
- Maxon (for Cinema 3D, free for students)
- Adobe (for AE, discounted for students)

However, basically I'm it in terms of direct involvement in the project.

Based on comments [here](http://www.dvxuser.com/V6/archive/index.php/t-149992.html) I could just do something like:

> A film by
>
> Me

Or alternatively I could go the path of

> Created by
>
> Me

Then I would add something like:

> Music "*tite*", by *composer*, CC-SA
>
> Based on the novel *title, published, publisher?*
>
> Model xyz by *modeller* CC-SA
>
> Graph Sample by *source* CC
>
> Special thanks to
>
> ```
>  Supervisor
>
>  Wife
>
>  Employer
> ```
>
> Copyright *Me* 2017, BY-NC-SA

Does the above seem reasonable? I'm a bit iffy on how to credit the author of the novel that the short is based on. Also what do about recognising Maxon and Adobe, or maybe I don't even need to go that far? I have to mention CC for assets that include as well as obligations on my work to be CC as a result.

Btw, I read through [What title(s) should a one-person film crew receive in the credit role?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12729/what-titles-should-a-one-person-film-crew-receive-in-the-credit-role), but it does not apply, as in my situation, I am a one person for everything, not just film.